# SQL Check conditions across multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table structure below. Now a student possessing prerequisite 1,2,3 comes and would like to know what courses he can take. The database should return course A & B for him.

I'm using mySQL, what SQL query I can use in this case?

Assume that the number of prerequisites per course varies, and the prerequisites possessed by the student is stored in an array in PHP.

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| course_id | prerequisite_id |
+-----------+-----------------+
| A         | 1               |
| A         | 2               |
| A         | 3               |
| B         | 2               |
| B         | 3               |
| C         | 4               |
| D         | 2               |
| D         | 3               |
| D         | 4               |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: In you sample data are you missing a B,1 maybe?

Comment: @Mihai There is no missing data. The student can take course B because course B only require prerequisite 2 & 3, which the student already possesses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
select
  course_id
from
  courses
where
  course_id not in (
    select
      course_id
    from
      courses
    where
      prerequisite_id not in (1,2,3)
  )
```

Edited: To just get the course.

```
SELECT
  course_id
FROM
  courses
WHERE
  course_id NOT IN (
    SELECT
      course_id
    FROM
     courses
    WHERE
      prerequisite_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
  )
GROUP BY course_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `having` clause for this:

```
SELECT course_id
FROM table t
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING SUM(case when prerequisite_id not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of prerequisites not met by the student.

If you want to exclude courses that have at least one of the set as pre-requisites:

```
SELECT course_id
FROM table t
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING SUM(case when prerequisite_id not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case when prerequisite_id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```